# Configure pgadmin4 to use Azure AD Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to add possibility to login into pgadmin4 panel with Azure AD Oauth2. I created app in `App registrations`, created secrets in `Certificates & secrets` and in `config_local.py` I have settings like:

```
    MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED = True
    AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['oauth2', 'internal']
    OAUTH2_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
    OAUTH2_CONFIG = [
      {
          'OAUTH2_NAME': 'azure',
          'OAUTH2_DISPLAY_NAME': 'azure',
          'OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID': 'Application (client) ID',
          'OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET': '{SECRET_VALUE}',
          'OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
          'OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_URL': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
          'OAUTH2_API_BASE_URL': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
          'OAUTH2_USERINFO_ENDPOINT': 'userinfo',
          'OAUTH2_BUTTON_COLOR': '#0000ff',
      }
    ]
```

I have an option on my login page to log into the panel with azure, but when I go there I get:

```
AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope email profile is not valid. openid scope is required.
```

From where should I take the scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error **`AADSTS70011`** usually occurs if you **missed** including scopes or provided **invalid** scopes.

You can add those scopes for your Azure AD application like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> Your App -> API permissions -> Add a permission***

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Based on the query, you need to add the scopes with spaces between them as a value for **`OAUTH2_SCOPE`** parameter.

For suppose if you are trying to read user profile, you need to include **"User.Read"** also like below:

```py
 'OAUTH2_SCOPE': 'User.Read openid email profile'
```

In addition to that, you need to change **`OAUTH2_API_BASE_URL`** and **`OAUTH2_USERINFO_ENDPOINT`** values too like below as **Azure** is your provider:

> ‘OAUTH2_API_BASE_URL’: ‘https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/', // Oauth
> base url
>
> ‘OAUTH2_USERINFO_ENDPOINT’: ‘me’, // Name of endpoint

To resolve the error, you need to modify your **`config_local.py`** file settings like below:

```py
    MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED = True
    AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['oauth2', 'internal']
    OAUTH2_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
    OAUTH2_CONFIG = [
      {
          'OAUTH2_NAME': 'azure',
          'OAUTH2_DISPLAY_NAME': 'azure',
          'OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID': 'Application (client) ID',
          'OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET': '{SECRET_VALUE}',
          'OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
          'OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_URL': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
          'OAUTH2_API_BASE_URL': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/',
          'OAUTH2_USERINFO_ENDPOINT': 'me',
          'OAUTH2_SCOPE': 'User.Read openid email profile' //Make sure to add User.Read in Portal too
          'OAUTH2_BUTTON_COLOR': '#0000ff',
      }
    ]
```

Make sure to add **Redirect URL** in your Azure AD application as `https://<your pgAdmin Server URL>/oauth2/authorize`

**CREDIT:** [How to Configure OAuth 2.0 with Azure AD in pgAdmin4 | by Asmita Thapliyal](https://medium.com/@asmita.thapliyal/how-to-configure-oauth-2-0-with-azure-ad-in-pgadmin4-2c1500d52d9d)

Comment: I can provide credentials to microsoft account know, but when I try to log in I get an error (on pgadmin4 login panel) `An email id is required to login into pgADmin. Please update your Oauth2 profile`

Comment: Hi @Frendom, please check the updated answer.

Comment: @Srodevi M thanks, endpoint `me` made me a day. It works like a charm now