# Can I configure pgadmin4 OAUTH2 redirect uri?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, pgadmin-4

I have a pgadmin server that I want to configure to use Azure AD for authentication.
I followed the instructions from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468988/configure-pgadmin4-to-use-azure-ad-oauth2", but when I click "log in", I get this error message:

> ADSTS50011: The redirect URI
> 'http://<MY DOMAIN>/oauth2/authorize' specified in
> the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the
> application '<MY CLIENT ID>'.

Now, it makes sense that the URI doesn't match, because the redirect URI that I registered starts with **https** and not **http**. In fact, Azure AD doesn't even allow non-ssl redirect URIs.

It also makes sense that pgadmin returns a redirect URI that starts with http. [That what the documentation says it does](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/oauth2.html#redirect-url).

I tried adding an automatic redirect from http to https on my server, but I don't know how that is supposed to work. My server is not visible to anyone but my org.

How can I configure pgadmin to return a redirect URI with https?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Thanks to SO [linking this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143288/7581), I realized it must be a missing X-Forwarded-Proto header from the reverse proxy.

I added this line to the nginx configuration:

```
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Now everything works.